# Replace nested select query by self join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, self-join

I recently asked a question here concerning an SQL query: [Trouble wrapping head around complex SQL delete query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15086335/1313143)

I now understand that what I'm trying to do is too complex to pull off with a single query or even multiple queries without some way to keep results in between. Therefore I decided to create a bash script (the end result will be something to do with a cronjob so bash is the most straightforward choice).

Consider the following table:

**AssociatedClient:**

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| Client_id | Registration_id |
+-----------+-----------------+
|         2 |               2 | 
|         3 |               2 | 
|         3 |               4 | 
|         4 |               5 | 
|         3 |               6 | 
|         5 |               6 | 
|         3 |               8 | 
|         8 |               9 | 
|         7 |              10 | 
+-----------------------------+
```

What I want to do is **select** all `Registration_id`s **where** the `Client_id` is **in** the list of `Client_id`s associated with a **specific** `Registration_id`.

Although I'm pretty noob with SQL, I found this query relatively easy:

```sql
SELECT `Registration_id` FROM `AssociatedClient` ac1
WHERE ac1.`Client_id` IN
                      (SELECT `Client_id` FROM `AssociatedClient` ac2 
                       WHERE ac2.`Registration_id` = $reg_id);
```

where `$reg_id` is just a bash variable.

**This works** but I would like to see it done with a **self join**, because it looks nicer, especially within a bash script where a lot of character clutter occurs. I'm afraid my SQL skills just don't reach that far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you should just be able to do a simple self join like so:

```
SELECT ac1.registration_id
FROM associatedclient ac1
JOIN associatedclient ac2 ON ac2.client_id = ac1.client_id
WHERE ac2.registration_id = $reg_id
```

So what you are doing is scanning the table once, joining it to itself where the client_id matches. Then you are restricting the joined rows to ones where the 2nd version of the table has a specific id, leaving you with the different permutations of the join on the 1st table, and then just picking the registration_id from those rows.

So, given the example of a variable value of 6, try running the following statement:

```
SELECT 
  ac1.client_id AS client_id_1
, ac1.registration_id AS reg_id_1
, ac2.client_id AS client_id_2
, ac2.registration_id AS reg_id_2
FROM associatedclient ac1
JOIN associatedclient ac2 ON ac1.client_id = ac2.client_id
```

and you'll notice the full set of joins. Then try adding the `WHERE` restriction and notice which rows come back. Then finally just pick the column you want.

You can check out a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fb4c/1) I set up which tests it with a value of 6

Comment: That seems to work :) I must admit that at the moment I don't fully understand why, but I'll try figure it out... Edit: okay your explanation makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to add an extra explanation. I'll update with a detailed step through if it will help you.

Comment: @tombom that was my bad. Originally I was selecting the `client_id`, should have been `registration_id`. I'll wait to accept this answer until I've seen more opinions.

Comment: @ChrisCameron-Mills thanks for your work. You also showed me that for optimalisation I needed to add `DISTINCT` and filter out the original ID. This query is a second level nested loop in my bash script so optimalisations like these do matter.

Comment: @tombom The fiddle was based on the explanation in the post which stated that the OP wanted to select a registration id. True, the original query might be fine but the question asked how it would be possible with a self join which is what my answer detailed.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester glad it helped. Yes, if you want to avoid duplicates a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` will help. If you are interested in how a self join and nested sub-query might affect performance of larger datasets you can look into query plans (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan)